# How to set a background image for a FabricJS object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to create a circle object and have the fill set as a non-repeating image.

I've tried this with a pattern, but when I set `repeat` to `no-repeat`, the pattern is offset in the middle, rather than top-left. (Which would allow you to see the whole image.)

1. Is there a way to set a whole image as the background of an object?
2. If not, is there a way to offset a non-repeating background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by clipping an image with a circle. Take a look at [this demo](http://fabricjs.com/clipping).

Pattern offsets is something that's been on a roadmap. I just went ahead and [implemented them](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/22de40dc54774d586ba7694446700f74feb27dad).

Take a look at [this demo](http://fabricjs.com/dynamic-patterns). Simply adjust offsetX/offsetY properties of a pattern to whatever you need, or leave them at 0/0 which would be left/top corner of an object.